# laravel how to route to a route on a javascript?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this jquery

```
$(".waitingTime .button").click(function () {
    alert("Ema");
});
```

I have a `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/20') }}"></a>
```

Can I do the same `href` action in the jquery function?

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you mean _same href action_?

Comment: @RahilWazir I mean like when I click on `a` tag, the browser goes to the href url. I would like to have the same feature in a javascript function. but here it is laravel, maybe it is different? I don't know

Answer (score 25, accepted):

yes this is possible and has nothing to do with Laravel.
There are different possibilities. If your query is embedded within the same laravel view, you  put the URL directly in your jQuery code, for example like this:

```
$(".waitingTime .button").click(function () {
  window.location.href = "{{URL::to('restaurants/20')}}"
});
```

But I think the best option is to add the URL on your button tag as a data attribute and then let jquery go to that URL. That way you can make your buttons more dynamic and have more capsulated code.

One example might be:

```
<div class="waitingTime">
  <button class="button link-button" data-href="{{URL::to('restaurants/20')}}">
  Click me
  </button>
</div>

$(".link-button").click(function () {
  window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
});
```

That way you can always give a button with the class `link-button` a `data-href` attribute with the URL you want to open when the button is clicked and don't have to add additional jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Just output php in your javascript

```
$(".waitingTime .button").click(function () {
    window.location.href = "<?php echo URL::to('restaurants/20'); ?>";
});
```

Comment: You should use laravel's synthax: `{{}}`. It applies some cool stuff.

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of this answer, php in javascript, it's rather average

Answer (score 0):

if need variable from js can use this

```
if(data.cookies == 0){
                  location.replace("{{ route('delivery') }}?id="+id);
                    }
```