# how can i add a route on the script?

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes

i wanna send a form but i use route and controller , so how can I replace it on $.post() ??

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $('#submit').text('درحال ارسال');
    $.post("send.php", $("#contactform").serialize(), function (response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
        $('#submit').text('ارسال');
        var data = JSON.parse(res);
        if (data.status == 1) {
            $('#result').addClass('green');
        } else {
            $('#result').addClass('red');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

it's the script in controller:

```
public function send()
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    //  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'info@unitech-ac.com';
    $subject = 'From unitech site';
    $message = "\r\n".'از طرف: '.$name."\r\n".'ایمیل: '.$email."\r\n".'متن پیام: '.$message;
    $headers = 'From: info@unitech-ac.com' . "\r\n";

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $res = [
        'status' => 1,
        'message'=> 'ایمیل شما با موفقیت ارسال شد'
        ];
        // echo json_encode($res);
        echo "ایمیل شما با موفقیت ارسال شد";
    } else {
        $res = [
        'status' => 0,
        'message'=> 'مشکلی در ارسال ایمیل پیش آمده، لطفا درخواست خود را مستقیما به ایمیل شرکت ارسال کنید'
        ];

        // echo json_encode($res);
        echo "مشکلی در ارسال ایمیل پیش آمده، لطفا درخواست خود را مستقیما به ایمیل شرکت ارسال کنید";
    }
}
```

and it's my route:

Route::post('/', 'ContactController@send')->name('send');

Thanks if you help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel how to route to a route on a javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353736/laravel-how-to-route-to-a-route-on-a-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can add route name in your `$.post` like below.

```
$.post("{{ route('send') }}", $("#contactform").serialize(), function (response) {
```

**Note : You need to add this jquery in your blade file. It will not work in seperate javascript file**

Comment: This will not work if the code is in a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: Yes Noted @Jerodev